# Существует ли еда, которая называется "чепуха"?

Tags: значение-слов

Существует ли еда, которая называется "чепуха"?  Встречалось ли вам это слово в применении к еде в живой речи (не в словарях и т.д.)?

Answer (score 1):

Не встречалось ни в живой речи, ни в словарях (за исключением соседства с продуктом питания в фразеологизме "чепуха на постном масле").